# Evoution fails to open since latest 16.04 update

Tags: evolution

I have been trying to get evolution to open/run have tried in terminal with the following result.
any advice on how to fix it ?

```
david@david:~$ sudo evolution %U
[sudo] password for david: 
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

(evolution:2957): GLib-ERROR **: /build/glib2.0-8EA4QF/glib2.0-2.48.1/./glib/gmem.c:100: failed to allocate 3748491972 bytes
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
david@david:~$
```

Comment: Never run applications exposed to the www like browsers or email applications as root (or with `sudo`) please. That's a serious security threat.

Comment: Which, btw, is also the source of your problem: the root user cannot access your desktop/screen (display ":0" belongs to your logged-in user, so the "failed to authenticate" was to be expected). As @ByteCommander pointed out: root/sudo is for system maintenance, not for running user applications.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too (Evolution offline after 16.04 update), but the suggestion in
 https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.16/offline.html.en , ie. to run

GIO_USE_NETWORK_MONITOR=base evolution

in a terminal window, with Evolution not running, worked.